# OpenCV DNN Java

Tags: java, opencv

I was trying to run an OpenCV program to run a DNN on an Android device using the OpenCv DNN module with Tensorflow and an SSD. However, I keep receiving this error when I try to run the program. CvException - cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.0) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:692: error: (-2.15:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'getMemoryShapes' I do not know how to fix this error because as far as I know, my code to access the protobuf and protobuf text file seems correct. My code to access the variables and read from them seem correct and the other OpenCV loaders are in other classes which seem to work fine. My code to access the pb and the pbtxt file are listed below:

```
public Mat processFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    final int IN_WIDTH = 300;
    final int IN_HEIGHT = 300;
    final double IN_SCALE_FACTOR = 1;
    final double MEAN_VAL = 0;
    final double THRESHOLD = 0.85;

    // Get a new frame
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, inputFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    // Forward image through network.
    Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(inputFrame, IN_SCALE_FACTOR, new Size(IN_WIDTH, IN_HEIGHT), new Scalar(MEAN_VAL, MEAN_VAL, MEAN_VAL), true, false);
    net.setInput(blob);

    List<List<Double>> blobList = new ArrayList<>();

    Mat detections = net.forward();

    int cols = inputFrame.cols();
    int rows = inputFrame.rows();


    detections = detections.reshape(1, (int) detections.total() / 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < detections.rows(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(detections);
        double confidence = detections.get(i, 2)[0];

        if (confidence > THRESHOLD) {
            int classId = (int) detections.get(i, 1)[0];
            int left = (int) (detections.get(i, 3)[0] * cols);
            int top = (int) (detections.get(i, 4)[0] * rows);
            int right = (int) (detections.get(i, 5)[0] * cols);
            int bottom = (int) (detections.get(i, 6)[0] * rows);

            List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(confidence);
            list.add(Double.valueOf(left));
            list.add(Double.valueOf(top));
            list.add(Double.valueOf(right));
            list.add(Double.valueOf(bottom));
            list.add(Double.valueOf(classId));

            blobList.add(list);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(blobList, new Comparator<List<Double>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<Double> a, List<Double> b) {
            return a.get(0) > b.get(0) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });

    Collections.reverse(blobList);

    int maxIndex = blobList.size() > 6 ? 6 : blobList.size();
    int numOfSkystone = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        List<Double> blobStuff = blobList.get(i);
        String detectedObj = "";


        double v = blobStuff.get(5).doubleValue();
        if (v == 3.0) {
            detectedObj = "Skystone";
            numOfSkystone++;
        } else if (v == 4.0) {
            detectedObj = "Stone";
        } else if (v == 2.0) {
            detectedObj = "Red Foundation";
        } else if (v == 1.0) {
            detectedObj = "Blue Foundation";
        } else {
            detectedObj = "Unknown";
        }

        String label = detectedObj + ": " + blobStuff.get(0);
        int[] baseLine = new int[1];
        Size labelSize = Imgproc.getTextSize(label, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1, baseLine);
        Imgproc.rectangle(inputFrame, new Point((int) blobStuff.get(1).intValue(), (int) blobStuff.get(2).intValue() - labelSize.height),
                new Point((int) blobStuff.get(1).intValue() + labelSize.width, (int) blobStuff.get(2).intValue() + baseLine[0]),
                new Scalar(255, 255, 255), Imgproc.FILLED);
        // Write class name and confidence.
        Imgproc.putText(inputFrame, label, new Point(blobStuff.get(0), blobStuff.get(2)),
                FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    }
    return inputFrame;
}
```

As far as I know, the code for that seems correct but I feel like the error may be within the pbtxt file, but I have no clue how to fix it. The pbtxt had to be attacked as a link mainly because of the reason that it is very very long close to 5000 lines and I ran the tf_graph_ssd.py file in order to generate it. However, all the lines in that too seem correct can anyone help me understand what is going wrong with it?

PB file, Pbtxt, config: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19g7xnC9ekjUHeFNtgcvSn2J1ioWmrb_L

Comment: Your last link is broken.

Comment: @Joachim Rohde, please take another look, I have re-edited the link with a proper one. Please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there were extraneous lines generated when trying to come up with a .pbtxt file. Deleting the first 40 lines ended up solving the problem.